Maintain offset when using bone constraints
[![enter image description here][1]][1]I was wondering if there is a way to maintain offset when adding track constraints to bones. I am currently trying to setup stretchy bone but when I add the stretch to constraint the bone jumps a bit which effects the skinning since the bone is not in bind pose i guess, and I notice that this issue is present with many more constraints. In Maya for reference you would simply check the maintain offset box and the bone would keep its original position/rotation.
Would be thankful for any tip.

hello, could you please share your armature?

Its classic biped created through AutoRig-Pro... but I dont really understand how that is supposed to answer the question of track constraints rotating bones.

if you are talking about Stretch To constraint, it should not jump, you probably need to move a bone in Edit mode, hard to say without the file or at least a screenshot

I added a screen of the stretchy bone in edit mode... when switched to pose mode the bone rotates to aim at the other orange bone seen in image (arm bones) ... which is also the target of the strechy bone

it doesn't help a lot, please share the armature (make the file as simple as possible, remove all the useless object and bones)

https://we.tl/t-wM7SoucFW9 - here is the scene... only spine and arm rig are present... the stretchy bone is at the armpit parented to spine and targeted to arm twist bone

if you are talking about armpit_stretch.l slightly rotating towards arm_twist_2.l, there's no way to avoid that except making armpit_stretch.l already point towards its target in Edit mode, you can for example make its tail stick to arm_twist_2.l's head

Damn... I noticed later that the deformation doesnt effect pose and object mode so the animators wont notice anything but I am still kinda shocked that Blender doesnt have any option to just keep the original position.... anyhow thank you so much for your time.

There is the Offset option for some constraints but not for this one as long as I know...
